# Android: can I filter for NFC tags with MIME-Type vnd.bluetooth.ep.oob?

Tags: android, bluetooth, nfc

I'd like my Android app to react to NFC tags which contain Bluetooth OOB setup records. My manifest contains:

```
<!-- intent filter for matching an NDEF MIME message. -->
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.bluetooth.ep.oob"/>
</intent-filter>
```

However, when I scan the tag, the app doesn't launch and the Bluetooth connection is started instead. Is there any way to handle these tags in my app? (Note: other intent filters for, e.g., URI tags work fine for launching my app, so it's probably specific to this MIME type.)

Answer (score 1):

As this is an [Android Application Record](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#aar), it bypasses all filters.
What you *can* do however, is make your activity implement the [Foreground Dispatch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch)

Using this, you'd have your activity open in order to intercept the intent, which you'll receive in

```
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
```

When using the intent filter approach, these intents are delivered through the `onResume()`, albeit this case is different.
The tags are delivered through `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` when using Foreground Dispatch, when the app actually is active.

Filter typed tags are delivered through the onResume(), as the application is launched from somewhere else. Depending on the tag, the intent will have a different action, which you can read all about at [the Android SDK Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#filtering-intents).

Comment: Are all NDEF messages with MIME-type `application/vnd.bluetooth.ep.oob` AARs?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make the tag to add the URI record to the first record of NDEF message. Because the first record is the NDEF Message's type. Then you can use URI intent-filter.